# Unnecessary border around mat-button-toggle

Tags: angular

When I click on mat-button-toggle unnecessary strange border appears. After it when I click somewhere else it hides. How can I remove this border?
I have both angular-material and bootstrap in my application. Can it be a reason for this problem(mixed-up styles or smth else) ?

[image] [image]

#### Code snippet:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group [(ngModel)]="selectedSize">
        <mat-button-toggle value="s">10''</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="m">12''</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="l">14''</mat-button-toggle>
      </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Comment: can u create demo on stackblitz? There is no same problem when i put this code in stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

use ngdeep in your css or scss file like:

```
::ng-deep mat-button-toggle-group{
  outline: none;
}
```

Thanks Danial

Comment: This does not work in Angular 11.